# Login form, text after checkbox

Tags: html, css, forms, checkbox

I'm doing a login form for a school project and for some reason I can't put a text after the checkbox without any element to move. I tryed `display: inline` property on the checkbox but still not working. There shoud be text "Remember me?" after the checkbox. Here is demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sa6y8epc/

Comment: You are styling the inputs all the same include checkbox.. try set this: input[type=checkbox]{ width: auto; height: auto;} - adjust your needs

Comment: Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sa6y8epc/3/

Comment: I think the problem is the `float: left`. But not only..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules set with `.login-div input` also apply to the checkbox. Change that, and remove the `float: left` from `#checkbox`

```
.login-div input[type=text],
.login-div input[type=password] { 
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 245px;
    height: 22px;
    padding: 2px;
    padding-left: 8px;
}

#checkbox  {
/*float: left;*/
}
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sa6y8epc/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Just resize the checkbox, e. g.:

```
#checkbox {
    width: 10px;
}
```

Then, basically, the text is on the right of the checkbox.

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sa6y8epc/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sa6y8epc/2/

Firstly add a label after the checkbox:

```
<label for="checkbox" id="checkbox-label">Remember me?</label>
```

And after that add this CSS:

```
.login-div {
    text-align: center;
}

#checkbox  {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

#checkbox-label { 
    font-size:12px; 
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top; 
    margin-top: 13px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the checkbox and the text in a label element (Check box will be clicked if you click on the Remember text as well. ). Please use the following code.

```
<label id="lbl-chkbx"><input type="checkbox" name="radio" id="checkbox"> Remember me </label>


input[type=checkbox]{ width: auto; height: auto;}
#lbl-chkbx{ vertical-align:-webkit-baseline-middle;}
```